# Boolean function arguments and returning

Tags: lua, roblox

so i know you can do stuff like this in lua to kind of shorten your code so you don't have to make unnecessary if statements

```
function checkMath(equation)
        if equation == 4 then
                return true
        end
        return false
end

workspace.Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.Green() or BrickColor.Red()
```

but is there a way to do that for a return statement inside a function?

basically, what I'm asking is: is it possible to return amount and items if returnItems is true or only amount if returnItems is false without a if statement?

what I've thought of doing (haven't tested):

```
countDictItems = function(tab,returnItems) 
    local amount = 0    
    local items = {}
    for _, ind in pairs(tab) do
        amount = amount + 1
    end
    return amount, items or amount
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered in a separate thread I posted on another website.

```
function blah(returnitems)
amount = 15
items = {"blah1", "blah2"}
return amount, returnitems and items or nil
end

print(blah(true))
print(blah(false))
```

output:

```
>15 table: 0x9e26e0
>15 nil
```